# Invoking multiple methods in controller or cover all calls in one method in service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know both ways would work, but I'm not sure which way would be more clean and flexible.

There is `OrderService` and it has the following methods:

- `searchOrders`
- `setBookableFlag`
- `mappingWithCarrier`

**Method 1:** Invoking all the methods in controller

`OrdersController`:

```
public OrderCarrierDTO searchOrders(@PathVariable carrierGuid){
   List<Order> orders = ordersService.searchOrders();
   ordersService.setBookableFlag(orders, carrierGuid);
   return orderService.mappingWithCarrier(orders, carrierGuid);
}
```

**Method 2:** Create a new method in Service and put all the callings in the method and invoke that new method from Controller:

`OrdersController`:

```
public OrderCarrierDTO searchOrders(@PathVariable carrierGuid){
   return orderService.searchOrdersForCarrier(carrierGuid);
}
```

Comment: it better to use Method 2 call same service once

Comment: @AbinashGhosh What about if `mappingWithCarrier` method is in another service, let's say `carrierService`?

Comment: Then you can call other service in controller since using a service in another service and vice-versa will cause a circular dependency .

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Method 2, Along with that you should ideally make all other three methods private and not accessible to the users of your service class.

That means the controller should not care if you call 3 or 30 methods inside your service, it should just know that if I call this method then it will get the output.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a good practice to maintain all the business logic in service and minimum code at controller layer, I would recommend the second approach. Assuming getting Orders for any Carrier is a frequent task, so maintaining a separate method (`searchOrdersForCarrier()`) in service for such tasks comes handy instead of calling multiple methods each time. if `searchOrders() setBookableFlag() mappingWithCarrier()` are also of reusable nature we can maintain them as separate methods and use them in `searchOrdersForCarrier()`.

Comment: What about if one of the methods is in another service. Let's say `mappingWithCarrier ` method is in another service?

Comment: I think it depends on the services you use, if `orderService` is dependent on `carrierService` and **not** vice-versa, approach 2 seems to be better by injecting `carrierService` into `orderService`. If `orderService` and `carrierService` are interdependent, injecting them into each other we would end up with circular dependency, then approach 1 works or we should restructure our services. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer method 2
The controller should only be handling input / output. So the job of the controller is receive the carrierGuid and pass that to the service which then does its thing. The result of this (or an exception) comes back to the controller and then the controller returns the proper http code / body for it